# Spring methodInvokingTimer, doesn't show the property

Tags: eclipse, spring, scheduling

I have imported the package `org.spring.schedule.timer2.5.6A`. using eclipse and created the following beans. My problem is I don't see / cant set any property values for the bean `methodInvokingTASK` (last one), where I should have.

```
property - targetObject

property - targetMethod
```

I don't know what is wrong, am I missing an import or doing anything silly!!!

```
<bean id = "scheduledTASK" class ="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="delay" value="1000" />
    <property name="period" value="6000"/>
    <property name="timerTask" ref="methodInvokingTASK" />
</bean>


<bean id="timerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
    <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
        <list>
            <ref local="scheduledTASK"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

    <bean id="methodInvokingTASK" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">

   </bean>
```

Comment: Hi, I think that a complete stacktrace would be useful

Comment: What is org.spring.schedule.timer2.5.6A?